# I can't seem to run this simple python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
however = ["In converse","On the other hand"]
furthermore = ["To add insult to injury","To add fuel to fire",]
conclusion = ["To ram the point home","In a nutshell"]
def prompt():
    answer = str(input("Type either 'however','furthermore' or 'conclusion': "))
    return answer
    reply()

def reply():
    if answer == "however":
        print(however)
    elif answer == "furthermore":
        print(furthermore)
    elif answer == "conclusion":
        print(conclusion)
    else:
        prompt()
    prompt()

prompt()
```

What is going on? it just doesnt print when i type in anything
it just skips and doesnt print anything at all

Comment: Your function call `reply()` is after the return statement. Thats the problem.

Comment: You need to do more research on functions, parameters, arguments, scope, execution order, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reply() function won't be called, because you exit the prompt() function by returning the answer

Here's how this should be done:

```
however = ["In converse","On the other hand"]
furthermore = ["To add insult to injury","To add fuel to fire",]
conclusion = ["To ram the point home","In a nutshell"]
def prompt():
    answer = str(input("Type either 'however','furthermore' or 'conclusion': "))
    reply(answer)
    return answer


def reply(answer):
    if answer == "however":
        print(however)
    elif answer == "furthermore":
        print(furthermore)
    elif answer == "conclusion":
        print(conclusion)
    else:
        prompt()
    prompt()

prompt()
```